# Locally closed differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry

If a differential form is locally closed, then is it closed? i.e. If it may be expressed as $d\alpha$ on a sufficiently small neighborhood around each point, then is it globally some $d\eta$?

Comment: No. It depends on the topology.

Comment: By the way, you mean locally exact and not locally closed. And locally exact is equivalent to closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property of a differential form to belong to the image of the exterior differential operator $\text{d}$ is called *exactness*, while being *closed* means to belong to the kernel of $\text{d}$. Any exact form is closed, but not vice versa - the difference is measured by de Rham cohomology.

The operator $\text{d}$ commutes with restriction to open subsets, and hence for differential forms being locally closed is the same as being closed. For exactness, however, this is wrong: *any* closed differential form is locally exact, since, by Poincare's lemma, closedness and exactness coincide for star-shaped regions in affine space.

Hence, you get an example of a locally exact but non exact differential form by taking any closed form which is not exact, such as $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(-y\cdot \text{d} x + x\cdot \text{d}y)$ on ${\mathbb R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.